# Starting cPanel service after changing default port number

Tags: web-services, server, cpanel

I am attempting to change the default cPanel port number on my server. I have located the cpanel.config file at:

```
/var/cpanel/cpanel.config
```

I have changed the **port number to 2001** and ran the two following commands:

```
 /usr/local/cpanel/whostmgr/bin/whostmgr2 --updatetweaksettings
 /etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

The result is the default port and cPanel link result in a 404. But attaching the new port number to the URL now fails to load the page. The URL I am now trying to access the cPanel from is:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com:2001
```

I am aware of similar questions but can't seem to find a response which is working for me. I have tried numerous port numbers to see if it was connected to the number I selected which it wasn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please new cPanel service port with the following command.

```
netstat -apn | grep 2001
```

If cPanel services is correctly binded on new port then enable 2001 port in your server firewall, Also please make sure port 2001 should be enable from your server provider.

Comment: I have ran the netstat command and it return `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2001                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      12528/cpsrvd (SSL)` and my firewall on the server is listening on port 2001 for connections.

Comment: I added a Temporary allow of my IP to the changed port number on the firewall in my WHM and that worked. Can't work out how to make that a permanent allow though.